# Why doesn't JSON.stringify() stringify my object as intended?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stringify

I'm making a fetch request from react-native. 
Why will **A** send the body data correctly, but **B** come back as undefined?

```
    let usrn = 'ususus'
    lew pwrd = 'pwpwpw'

    let bodyData = {
        'u': usrn,
        'p': pwrd,
    }
```

Specifically the body data with `JSON.stringify()`?

```
=> A
    return fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'u': usrn,    // <= can return this value on server
                'p': pwrd,    // <= can return this value on server
            })
        })

=> B
    return fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify({ bodyData }) // <= returns undefined on server
        })
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`bodyData` is an object, you don't need to wrap it with curly brackets again:

```
body: JSON.stringify(bodyData);
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought this was it but I could get it to work.

Comment: when I saw the question, my mind starts to think about the `us` undefined xD but, yeah you're right

Comment: There is two problems in your second approach, the `{}` and also what @Kenry mentioned. So you will have to fix that as well

Comment: Thanks to both of you typo fixed.

Comment: Thanks, guys xD  @denden

Answer (score 2):

variable `us` is not defined..

```
let bodyData = {
    'u': us,
    'p': pwrd,
}
```

In the code:

```
return fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'u': usrn,    // <= can return this value on server
            'p': pwrd,    // <= can return this value on server
        })
    })
```

you are using the property `'u'` the variable `usrn`. it is defined

Change bodyData to..

```
let bodyData = {
'u': usrn,
'p': pwrd,
```

}

Comment: body: JSON.stringify(bodyData);. Yes, but this is the right answer. the guy has right